# Function : Updating & printing a dictionary with the most recent values

Tags: python

I've created a function : A dictionary which takes in city name and country name to which the city belongs to. Currently the code just returns a dictionary after each iteration with city name and country name after taking inputs using the input(). I'm trying to update the code (no success so far) so that a new dictionary is printed after each iteration with updated dictionary which returns an output like

```
{'city' : 'berlin', 'country' : 'germany',
 'city' : 'paris',  'country' : 'france',}
```

The code is as follows :

```
def city_country(city_name, country_name):
    pair = {'City': city_name, 'Country': country_name}
    return pair


active = True
while active:
    user_city = input("Enter city name : ")
    if user_city == 'q':
        break
    user_country = input("Enter country name : ")
    if user_country == 'q':
        break
    new_pair = city_country(user_city, user_country)
    print(new_pair)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys of the dictionary type are unique, this way of writing you can always print only one city and one country, maybe you can try to do it in json format, but it means you have to write another function to deal with the duplication of data (directly add or replace)

```
def city_country(city_name, country_name):
    return {'City': city_name, 'Country': country_name}


data = []
while True:
    user_city = input("Enter city name : ")
    if user_city == 'q':
        break
    user_country = input("Enter country name : ")
    if user_country == 'q':
        break
    data.append(city_country(user_city, user_country))
    print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
city_country_dict = {}
active = True
while active:
    user_city = input("Enter city name : ")
    if user_city == 'q':
        break
    user_country = input("Enter country name : ")
    if user_country == 'q':
        break
    new_pair = city_country(user_city, user_country)
    #=================================
    city_country_dict.update(new_pair)
    #=================================
    print(city_country_dict)
```

Comment: city_country_dict.update(new_pair) -----> Throws 'Unresolved reference' error.

Comment: You missed declaration. Make sure you add `city_country_dict = {}`. Also, onething, in the question itself, You cannot add same keys multiple times.. So, `{'city' : 'berlin', 'country' : 'germany',
 'city' : 'paris',  'country' : 'france',}`, itself, cannot happen. You may try some other designs.

Comment: Could you kindly modify the code above and show ? I'll run it over directly and see. Looks like i'm missing something.